# How to bypass Login-Screen in Windows 10 after standby?

Tags: windows-10, reboot, standby, auto-login, autologon

I have a client running Windows 10 Home, and a user without a password that I have setup for automatic logon after boot. This works fine if I completely boot the computer from power-off leading to the user seing the desktop after boot without further interaction.

Why is the same not possible after standby or hibernate? If the computer is set set to standby or hibernate and wakes up, I always see two(!) screens: first, some picture I don't want to see that Windows takes somehere and which is totally useless, and when this picture is clicked, I get a second screen with a button labeled "Login", and only after these two clicks I am taken to the desktop.

I don't really know why the behaviour for automatic logon is different if a user reboots completely or from hibernation, so is there any way to fix that and always be taken to the desktop directly?

Answer (score 1):

**Method One:**

Yes, you can disable **Require password** feature after screen goes off or Wake up from sleep:

1. Click **Settings -> Accounts**.
2. Click **Sign-in options** on the left side.
3. Select **Never (off)** under **Require sign in**.
4. When finished, you can close Settings to restart to check the result.

**Method Two:**

Open the **advanced power settings** for your current chosen **power plan**.
Click on the Change settings that are currently unavailable link. (see screenshot below)

[image]

3. Set the Require a password on wakeup settings to No.

Comment: Both of this options aren't available on windows lstc 2021